# Returning lambda from function with passed in reference capture

Tags: c++, lambda

Is it safe returning a lambda like this:

```
auto doIt(const Object& obj) {
    return [&obj]{ obj.doIt();};
}
```

It returns a lambda using local capture, but the reference is one that is passed into the function and not from a local variable.

Comment: As long as the reference obj has longer lifetime than lambda, it is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
auto doIt(const Object& obj) {
    return [&obj]{ obj.doIt();};
}
```

That's probably not a good idea for the mere fact that `doIt(const Object& obj)` can bind a temporary object. Imagine doing:

```
auto lm = doIt(make_object());
lm();                                 //Undefined behavior
```

That's because the temporary returned my make_object would be destroyed at the end of the function `doIt`, but your returned lambda still holds a reference to the destroyed object.

Another example will be:

```
auto func(){
    Object obj = make_object();
    auto lm = doIt(obj);
    lm();                            //This is Ok
    return lm;
}

void something{
    auto val = func();
    val();                           //Undefined Behavior
}
```

---

*EDIT: See the comments*.

You can add a `void doIt(const Object&&) = delete;` overload to prevent temporaries; Courtesy of @StoryTeller.

Comment: You can have your cake and eat it too. Add a `auto doIt(Object&&) = delete` overload, and you can keep your code const correct, without risking the first UB.

Comment: @StoryTeller, umm that doesn't prevent a corner case like `const Object getObj(){ return {}; }`

Comment: `auto doIt(Object const &&) = delete` would, I think. A use for const rvalue references, at last :)

Comment: @StoryTeller, of-cause, that does it... :-).

Comment: I'm however a moron for leaving the return type of a deleted function as deducible. So a final (and hopefully correct) attempt `void doIt(Object const &&) = delete`.

Comment: @StoryTeller, While I still think the OP's `doIt(const Object&)` function is fragile, I agree with your suggestion. Answer modified; ...

Comment: No arguing it's fragile. But its nice to exercise obscure language features from time to time :)

Comment: In my case the use is always local to the calling function, so unless there is more to it than the lifetime of of the reference it seems safe for that then. But of course a less fragile option would be better.